# Selenium cant click element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So recently I came across this error and get around it. I have selenium set up in a way that a user enters text and the search bar on https://www.dukascopy.com/trading-tools/widgets/quotes/historical_data_feed displays the data however I can't click the result with my code.[image: the data i am trying to access]

Comment: That search bar is inside an `iframe` tag. You'll need to switch to that `iframe` to interact with the element -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python?rq=1

Comment: there were two nested iframes and i tries switching them in every possible way but i couldnt select the option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go. The search bar needed to be toggled through a button click.

```
... # Driver initialization, navigating to the page etc.

# The first nested frame
frame_1 = driver.find_element_by_id("widget-container")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_1)

# The second nested frame
frame_2 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_2)

# Toggling the search bar
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Instrument')]").click()

# Actually sending in the query
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Instrument']")
search.send_keys("Hey there!")
```